# How to export a .AVI as a sequence of images in Avidemux

Tags: avi

I'm trying to simply export every frame of an **.AVI** movie as a sequence of images (**.tiff**) or a folder of **.jpeg** images.

[This web page](http://www.digital-photo-software-guide.com/avi-to-jpeg.html) says I can simply select all frames in Avidemux, then go to:

*File --> Save --> Save JPEG image*

But that only ends up saving one frame instead of the entire selection. Any thoughts?

I'm using **Avidemux version 2.6.10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade to 2.5 since 2.6 does not support [image sequence](http://avidemux.org/smif/index.php?topic=11632.0) export.

Alternatively, you could download [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and run

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -q:v 1 in%d.jpg

ffmpeg -i input.avi in%d.tif
```

Comment: Thanks! Avidemux 2.5.6 totally works.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/avidemux/files/avidemux/2.5.6/